# "Data source name not found and no default driver"

Tags: java, mysql, odbc

java to mysql connection code:

```
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "sai");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connection established");
```

after excution of above code

```
"Driver loaded" message printed on console but,
after that following exception is printed - 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

i have already create DSN(MYSQL ODBC 3.51 Driver) for project

Please tell me solution of above problem.

Comment: You haven't told us your url, which makes it a bit harder to diagnose...

Comment: Your tags were "java swing struct", which is close to your headline `swing components and struct java programming`, which has nothing to do with the text. I will edit it too. Please be a bit more careful. And please emphasize what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If somehow possible, don't use a JdbcOdbc driver, but a pure JDBC-Driver for your database!

For the question of how to register the driver, from the javadocs for java.sql, Interface Driver:

> It is strongly recommended that each
>   Driver class should be small and
>   standalone so that the Driver class
>   can be loaded and queried without
>   bringing in vast quantities of
>   supporting code.
>
> When a Driver class is loaded, it
>   should create an instance of itself
>   and register it with the
>   DriverManager. This means that a user
>   can load and register a driver by
>   calling
>
> ```
> Class.forName("foo.bah.Driver")
> ```

A separate call to 'newInstance' or registerDriver' is Cargo-Cult-programming.

Answer (score 1):

"If somehow possible, don't use a JdbcOdbc driver, but a pure JDBC-Driver for your database!"

An example MySql pure JDBC-Driver would be the **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** class found in the **mysql-connector-java-5.x.x.jar** file available for download from [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

A good explanation of the differences between JDBC and JDBC-ODBC are available on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver)

Answer (score 0):

It's a while since I've done this, but you could try to explicitly register your driver with the DriverManager class. This means that you're not depending upon something unseen implicitly happening in the background.

```
DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) 
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance());
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "sai");
```

This will ensure that the "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" class is loaded and connected to the DriverManager.

Comment: .newInstance isn't necessary, `registerDriver` the same. And don't hide Exceptions: `catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace (); }`
"Data source name not found" is the error - maybe the URL? I don't know what it looks like for mysql.

Comment: Please see my updated posting (because the layout wouldn't work that well in the comments), where I'm citing the javadocs.